# How to add icon to iOS notification

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, ios10

I have a requirement to show the icon in the notification, I am not able to find out any way provided by the iOS directly, the image supported by iOS notification doesn't work well as the icon. Does anyone have some idea about adding the icon to the notification which workes well, I have seen this Whatsapp notification and wondering how it's done?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify. By icon you mean the warning or whatsApp notification itself?

Comment: The warning icon in the notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not an icon. That's an emoji: ⚠️ (WARNING SIGN U+26A0). Emojis are just characters and can be included in the text portion of the notification.

Comment: is that possible to add some type custom emoji in iOS notification, which iOS looks for in-app or something?

Comment: No. There is no such thing as custom emoji. Emoji are just characters that happen to look like images. But they're fundamentally no different than the letter A or the character 我. If you want to know what emoji Apple supports and what they look like on iOS see https://emojipedia.org/apple/

Comment: (Technically you *could* have custom emoji if you created your own custom font, but that wouldn't be used in system notifications like this one. Creating a font is very different than creating an image, though.)

Comment: So custom font doesn't show in notification even included as files?

Comment: Correct; notifications are generated by the system and use the system font.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. +1